# T9 Torx Screw Thread diameter in Metric System

Tags: design, cad, bolting

Helllo, 
I have to design a part that will have screws that can be taken apart with a T9 Torx Screwdriver. These are the screws that are taken apart first thing [here](https://youtu.be/cc3bkyk1PBc?t=17).
What is the thread diameter of the screw that mates with the T9 torx screw in the Metric System?

On [this](https://www.insight-security.com/what-is-a-torx-screw) website they mention "point-to-point" dimensions. But I am unable to understand what that refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Torx defines the head only, it can be used on metric or SAE screw sizes.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx), the point-to-point distance is the "diameter of circle circumscribed on the cross-section of the tip of the screw driver."